Expected value of X^3
If $X$ is an arbitrary random variable with $E(X)=0$, then $E(X^3)=0$?

$\mathbb{E}X^3$ is a measure of symmetry for the distribution, so for the normal distribution for example, it is true that $\mathbb{E}X^3=0$, but for general distributions this is not true.

In short, no in general.
Consider the three roots of $x^3-1=0$. Note that Vieta's formula its three roots: $r_1,r_2,r_3$ sum to $0$. Consider a random variable $X$ having equal probability ($\frac{1}{3}$ for each) to be $r_i, i=1,2,3$. Then $E[X]=0$. However, we know $X^3=1$. Hence $E[X^3]\neq 0$ in this case.

This is a fantastic example.

You are violating the rules of the site. See: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1

One might be a little disappointed as well that this is not a real valued random variable.
